# Indexing in C strings

Tags: c, pointers, char, c-strings

I've been tasked for school as projects to create an assembler (translate assembly into machine language) and a simulator (translate machine language into the assembly language instructions).  My one issue is with C-strings. I'll paste the relevant code but I manage to load a character array capable of holding 33 characters (32 for the bits, one for the null terminator).  I have successfully translated the machine language into its proper 32 bit instruction. However, when I try to index certain bits of the char array it gives me segmentation faults which confuses me. I didn't include all the code but the troubling part is in the for loop when i try to determine if there's an add opcode. Consider everything else to be done properly and tested.Thanks

```
typedef struct stateStruct {
    int pc;
    int mem[NUMMEMORY];
    int reg[NUMREGS];
    int numMemory;
 } stateType;


char line[MAXLINELENGTH];
char instruction[33];
stateType state;
state.pc=0;
FILE *filePtr;

int i;
int reg1,reg2;

for(i=state.pc;i<state.numMemory;i++){

    //noop
    if(state.mem[state.pc]==29360128){

    }
    //halt
    if(state.mem[state.pc]==25165824){

    }

    if(decimalToBinary(state.mem[state.pc],instruction)){
        //add instruction
        printf("%s\n",instruction);//This prints out a 32 bit string of 0 and 1
        if(instruction[7]==0 && instruction[8]==0 && instruction[9]==0){
            printf("add instruction");
            //Search for the first register 
            reg1=registerValue(instruction+10);
            printf("%d\n",reg1);
            //Search for the second register
            reg2=registerValue(instruction+13);
            printf("%d\n",reg2);
        }

    }
    else{
        exit(1);
    }
    state.pc++;
}



return(0);
}


int decimalToBinary(int decimal,char *instruction){

int i;
char binary[33];
int temp;
int x=0;

for(i=31;i>=0;i--){
    temp=pow(2,i);
    if(decimal%temp == decimal){
        binary[x]='0';
    }
    else{
        binary[x]='1';
        decimal=decimal%temp;
    }
    x++;
}   
strncpy(instruction,binary,32);
}

int registerValue(char *instruction){
int reg=0;
int i=2;
while(i>=0){
    if(*instruction=='1'){
        reg=reg+pow(2,i);
    }
    instruction++;
    i--;
}
return reg;
}
```

Comment: Do you even initialize "state.numMemory"?  I don't see it being anywhere but you are looping until "i<state.numMemory".  This could be one possible issue.  Let me know so I can analyze this more in depth.  EDIT:  Also what is the last print statement (if any) that you see in the output?  So we know about where it's crashing.

Comment: ya state.numMemory is initialized, everything is initialized properly, and when i printf instruction it prints out the correct 32 bitcode. It just has an issue when I try to index instruction

Comment: From the `strncpy` man page: *Warning: If there is no null byte among the first `n` bytes of `src`, the string placed in `dest` will not  be null-terminated.* So check `strncpy(instruction,binary,32);`

Comment: Can you print out "state.mem[state.pc]" that you pass to "int decimalToBinary(int decimal,char *instruction)" as the "decimal" parameter?

Comment: Have you run it within `gdb` or another debugger? What is the value of `instruction` at the time you are indexing it?

Comment: Also, you're aware that there is no "return" statement in your "int decimalToBinary()", correct?  Is that intended?

Comment: @MrHappyAsthma I can print it out each time. For example, the content of state.mem[0] is 8454151 and it translates to the proper 32 bit loaded in instruction.

Comment: @MrHappyAsthma that was an accident, i changed it to return 1,

Comment: @mbratch I didn't realize that so i changed it to 33 bits. Do you think it has to do with not being null terminated which causes the segfault

Comment: The functions themselves work.  I've done a few tests and examined them and couldnt find an issue.  You could be printing out garbage since you don't null terminate your C-String and use "%s" to print.

Comment: `strncpy` doesn't automatically insert a null termination. So the `33` value for `n` is OK as long as the source string ends in a null (it will be copied since it's comprehended in the number of bytes you indicated, 33). If there's no null in the source string `binary` within the first 33 characters, then it won't help. Fixing this issue will help eliminate segfaults, but this may not be the only cause.

Comment: Add this:  binary[32] = '\0';
strncpy(instruction,binary,33);  It probably won't fix your issue, but itl help prevent future ones.

Comment: i thought this would fix it. I put binary[32]='\0' than changed strncpy to copy the first 33 characters which would copy the null terminator. This is really baffling me, any more information i can provide

Comment: Ive ran as much of the code as possible with hardcoded values for those missing and I cannot reproduce any such error.  If there is an error in your code, I'm guessing its not from the section on the screen.  Perhaps other variables whose initializations aren't shown are causing a problem:  i.e. state.mem[], state.numMemory, MAXLINELENGTH, NUMMEMORY, NUMREGS.  Or somewhere else you are accessing outside of array bounds and its messing with this array as well.  Something along those lines.